# jquery - Search and Replace via a Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is dynamically populated and I want to replace all occurrences in a column with values in a Switch/Case statement.   There is code in there already but it only changes values in the first row (code below).

Because the table is dynamically populated, I don't know how many rows there will be and I have no control over how it is populated - I can only add HTML tags or JavaScript, the rest is a black box.

Hopefully I've explained properly and I apologise for my lack of knowledge in this area.

HTML:

```
<td><span id="status_code">1</span></td><td><span id="status_code">2</span> 
</td><td><span id="status_code">3</span></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
if(typeof status_code === "function"){
$("#status_code").text(status_code( $("#status_code").text() ));
}
</script>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
function Status_Code(code){
switch(code){
case "1" : return "Status 1";
case "2" : return "Status 2";
case "3" : return "Status 3";
default: return code;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please use classes instead of ids if you need more of one element with the same one.

Comment: id should be unique, you cant have duplicated ids, use class instead. I think what you want to do is select all span with queryselector and iterate on every element

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you should use a `class` instead of duplicated IDs.

And then simply use jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the `span`s.

This can easily be done without jQuery, which is a good idea if you're not already using it for a bunch of other stuff.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/uvhprL8n/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="status_code">1</span></td>
        <td><span class="status_code">2</span></td>
        <td><span class="status_code">3</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.status_code').each(function() {
    $(this).text(Status_Code($(this).text()));
});

function Status_Code(code) {
    switch(code) {
        case "1" : return "Status 1";
        case "2" : return "Status 2";
        case "3" : return "Status 3";
        default: return code;
    }
}
```